# Which is the best way to develop this UI?

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I'm trying to develop a particular UI, but I have some problems.
In my UI there are two main blocks of `ImageViews`and `EditTexts`and under each block there is an `ExpandableListView`:
[image: main UI]

The main problem it's with the `ExpandableListView`, because i want that when those lists expands and the layout became bigger than the screen , the screen became scrollable. But if I put a scrollview, only the list that goes out of the screen became scrollable.
I've tryed different solutions but nothing worked... 
So what's the best way to do this? witch layout it's better?

Comment: Please show us the code/definition for the entire layout. It sounds like you're putting the ExpandableListView into the scrollview, not the entire application window.

Comment: Yes, i've put the list inside the scrollview, because i don't know where put that outside without getting an error...

Comment: Can you please provide the layout definition (either java or xml, whichever you're using)?

Comment: What i'm looking for with this question it's a good method to develop this layout, not to fix my buggy code.

Comment: My suggestion would be to rethink your design -- it would be very difficult for a user to navigate successfully, especially if you have two listviews on a single page, each with expandable items. If you're dead-set on implementing this, you may have to roll your own -- place row items in a `LinearLayout`, and wrap the entire layout in a `ScrollView` -- so the "lists" appear static and the entire screens pans. Of course, you'd lose goodies like view recycling, and you would have to write a lot of the plumbing yourself.

Comment: yeah, i think i will have to implement the list's graphics by myself

Comment: For the ExpandableListView's, how many groups need to show up there? Is it only one group with a bunch of children under it?  Side question, is this for tablets only or cell phones too?

Comment: Yes, it's only one group with 4-5 children. It's for phones and tablet.